# overloading operator -> to access data member

Tags: c++, c++11

I have a question about the following sample program about overloading -> operator, same across in a C++ tutorial:

```
 5     class myclass
 6     {
 7         public:
 8         int i;
 9
10         myclass *operator->()
11         {return this;}
12     };
13
14     int main()
15     {
16         myclass ob;
17
18         ob->i = 10;
19         cout << ob.i << " " << ob->i << endl;
20
21         return 0;
22     }

$ ./a.out
10 10
```

I am trying to understand how line 18 works.  I understand that "ob" is not a pointer, but since "class myclass" has defined the operator "->", "ob->i" is valid (syntactically), so far good.  However, "ob->" returns a pointer, and I don't see how it is de-referenced to get access to member "i" and setting it.

I am assuming the above explanation will also explain how in line 19 "ob->i" is printed as an int.

Thank you,
Ahmed.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`x->y` is equivalent to `x.operator->()->y` if `x` is a class object and an overloaded member `operator->` is found.

I hope it gets clearer from that.

Comment: Fair enough.  Just one more question, when you say "x->y is equivalent to x.operator->()->y ..."  is that per the C++ language spec.

Comment: @AhmedA well it is not always equivalent to that, but only when `x` is a class object and an overloaded member `operator->` is found. Yes, that is by the language spec.

Comment: In particular, the Standard says "When operator-> returns, the operator -> is applied to the value returned, with the original second operand."

Comment: Thank you very much for the detailed / supported answer, awesome.

Answer (score 7):

`operator->` gets called in a chain until it can no longer get called - in your case, it's actually called twice - once, the overloaded operator on your object, which returns a pointer, and the second time, the built-in operator which dereferences that pointer and accesses that member.

Comment: Great answer! Learn something every day. Is there a way to chain it further? (e.g. -> returns point to an object, and that object also overloads it to something)

Comment: @Shingetsu: Yes, but it requires `operator->` to return an object, not a pointer.  `operator->` of the returned object will then be called.  As soon as any pointer is encountered, the built-in `->` behavior will be triggered.

Comment: Can you please elaborate, why the built-in -> operator is getting called the second time.  If is possible for you to expand, in steps, how/why the second -> is called.  Thank you.

Comment: @AhmedA that's the standard behaviour. Not much more to explain after that.

Comment: I am surprised the program doesn't get into an infinite loop.

Comment: @RSahu: Why would you think the program might get into an infinite loop?

Comment: @DigitalEye My misunderstanding. I see now why it won't.